# WPF application Sqlserver CE in backend.Deploying exe is issue in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have using `Sql Compact edition 4.0` as Database,My application is on `WPF (.Net framework 4.0)`. At the time of making executable file facing error as below

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlserverCe,
>   version=4.0.0.1,culture=neutral,publicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies located assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.(Exception from HRESULT:0x80131040).

Please help anyone to solve this...I have added extra folder as per one of the answer.
`MicrosoftSqlServerCompact/v4.0/private.`
and also added references of two dll from that folder.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by changing framework of both and its work perfectly. Thanks! @kurubaran

Answer (score 0):

> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference

Application expecting a version of the dll other than what is available. basically you have added dll with different version.

Comment: So which version I can use..Is there problem in adding reference or folder named "Private"? Error when creating build:"ISEXP:error : -6017: The build was unable to extract COM information; make sure that you are running as Administrator."

Comment: Check the project > Reference and see the version of the dll

Comment: Version 4.0.0.1 and runtime version is v2.0.50727 while for sql server entity dll reference having runtime version v4.0.30319. But everything work fine in my PC when I run exe.(windows 8.64 bit.).other PC having issue(windows 7 or XP)

Comment: @shivoham Did you check the processor architecture of other PC where ist nto working ? is it 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: yes it is of 64 bit..on which it is not working.right now added other DLL as reference which are present in Private/amd and Private/x86.this private folder is in my project.

Comment: In how many project you have referenced System.Data.SqlserverCe ? after deploying to other machine can you get the dll from installation folder and check the version ?

Comment: But got error again Error when creating build:"ISEXP:error : -6017: The build was unable to extract COM information; make sure that you are running as Administrator."

Comment: In one project only...But now on time of build project I'm facing issue.